# How to fix a leak in pipe valve?

Tags: leak, pipe, valve

I am an amateur. There is a leak in this pipe valve. Water is dripping. Should I try to fix it myself (how?), or call a plumber?

[image]

Comment: Where is the valve leaking from? How are the PVC pipes connected to the brass valve?

Comment: If this is a brand new installation, and the leak from the valve stem is minimal, it may just stop a few days later as PETF bushing swells. I had that experience a couple months ago. If however it is a significant leak, please post where it is.

Answer (score 1):

If the leak is from under the nut at the handle, remove the nut and the handle. Under the handle may be a nut. If so this is a packing nut. Tighten the nut clockwise just a bit at a time until the drip quits. If there is no packing nut then replace the handle and tighten the nut for the handle: this nut could be doing double duty as a packing nut and to hold the handle on. If neither attempt stops the drip you may have to replace the valve.